# statsmodels api logic with categorical dependent variable

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to run `statsmodel.api.Logit()` function for to predict a binary variable using some continuous variables and one categorical feature. (let's Say the categorical variable input is `(Red, Green, Blue)`.
When I run:

```
model = Logit(np.array(y_train.astype(float)), X_train.astype(float))
result = model.fit()
print(result.summary())
```

I get a coefficient for `feature_red`, `feature_green`, and `feature_blue`. Isn't this introducing multi-colinarity? If not, how do I interpret the coefficients?

Comment: I guess you onehot encoded. it is the log odds ratio of being 1 for each category. Looks like you did not use an intercept, so this should be fine

Comment: What's `X_train.astype(float)`? If you don't use the formula interface to models, then statsmodels takes the data as given. `X_train.astype(float)` is outside statsmodels and depends on the type of `X_train`. Can you make a executable example (with fake data) to show what the behavior is.

Comment: You can check the eigenvalues (or vif) of `model.exog` to see how close to collinear it is. Logit cannot handle singular design matrices. So if the convergence and results look fine. then multicollinearity cannot be close to perfect collinearity.

Comment: Also, statsmodels does not add an intercept if you are not using the formula interface. Having all dummies for 1 categorical variable included makes that collinear with a constant. But if there is no constant, then there is no collinearity.